# Allocating resources to VPS's

Tags: centos, openvz

I need a layman's term definition of these parameters and what they do in terms of allocating resources to servers, as I'm having issues with the VPS's that I set up, as Java seems to be unable to set up a virtual machine on them for minecraft unless they have over 2Gb's of each parameter, and I'm assuming I must be doing something wrong. Here is the current script exert that I use to initially create the server and assign resources:

```
SERVID=$1
IPPICK=$2
HOSTNAME=$3
PW=$4
EMAIL=$5

if vzctl create $SERVID --ostemplate centos-6-x86_64.2 --config vps.packtwo-basic ;
    then
        echo -e "\nVPS container was successfully created...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "Please restart the package install, there was a problem creating the VPS..."
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --onboot yes --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nSet to boot on start...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, the onboot config went wrong...\n"
        exit $?
fi

if vzctl set $SERVID --ipadd $IPPICK --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nIP added to the VPS successfully...\n"
    else
        echo -e "\nThe IP address used, may be used on another server, this may mean that the server has an issue contacting external addresses..\n"
fi

if vzctl set $SERVID --hostname $HOSTNAME --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nHostname assigned to the VPS successfully...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem assigning the Hostname to the VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --swappages=2224M:2224M --save;
        then
                echo -e "\nThe Swap Pages were successfully allocated...\n"
        else
                vzctl stop $SERVID
                vzctl destroy $SERVID
                echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating Swappages to this VPS...\n"
                exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --userpasswd root:$PW --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe root password was successfully assigned...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem assigning the chosen password for the root account...\n"
        exit $?
fi

#Resource double checking
if vzctl set $SERVID --diskspace 30G:32G --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe resources were successfully allocated...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating resources to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi

if vzctl set $SERVID --quotatime 800 --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe burst settings were successfully added...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating quta burst time to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi


#Add RAM
if vzctl set $SERVID --vmguarpages 1124M --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe Vmguarpages have been successfully allocated...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating Vmguarpages to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --physpages 1124M:1124M --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe RAM was successfully allocated...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating the RAM to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --privvmpages 1124M:1124M --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe Privvmpages have been successfully allocated...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating Privvmpages to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl set $SERVID --oomguarpages 1124M --save;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe Oomguarpages was successfully allocated...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating Oomguarpages to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
if vzctl start $SERVID;
    then
        echo -e "\nThe VPS was successfully started...\n"
    else
        vzctl stop $SERVID
        vzctl destroy $SERVID
        echo -e "\nPlease restart the package install, there was a problem allocating resources to this VPS...\n"
        exit $?
fi
```

Comment: The minecraft server fails to start with less ram because by default the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` settings in the `run.sh` are 2GB or higher.

Comment: No they're not, they're set to 1024Mb's. It's not a standard minecraft server I'm running, it's a minecraft server with a panel. All of it, is set to the correct resources and such.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't run Java applications such as Minecraft on OpenVZ. Even if you get past this hurdle, the performance is going to be terrible.

Comment: Well, I currently have one running and the performance is terrific, so you clearly know nothing.